# Can't find a codec for class com.mongodb.client.model.geojson.Point

Tags: mongodb, geojson, mongodb-java

The following throws **org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class com.mongodb.client.model.geojson.Point.**

```
import com.mongodb.client.model.geojson.Point;
import com.mongodb.client.model.geojson.Position;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception{
    BasicDBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();
    dbo.put("name", "some-name");
    dbo.put("location", new Point(new Position(100, 200)));
    System.out.println(dbo.toJson());
}
```

What am I missing? All I wanted is to see how Java driver serializes my object into JSON. (MongoDB java driver version 3.8.0)

Comment: The error exactly states that it can't find the codec for your class (that is, the class that serializes your object into BSON). I haven't used the java driver that much, but you probably need to add PointCodec (https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.1/com/mongodb/client/model/geojson/codecs/PointCodec.html) into your CodecRegistry.

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the problem, the default codecs in BasicDBObject are not covering the geoJSON stuff. Not sure that what I did is correct but it seems to work.

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception{
    CodecRegistry cr = fromProviders(new ValueCodecProvider(), new BsonValueCodecProvider(), new DBObjectCodecProvider(), new GeoJsonCodecProvider());
    codec = cr.get(BasicDBObject.class);

    BasicDBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();
    dbo.put("name", "some-name");
    dbo.put("location", new Point(new Position(100, 200)));
    System.out.println(dbo.toJson(codec));
}
```